# Create global environmental variable after boot

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, gpg, gpg-agent

I know about /etc/profile and /etc/environment, but I would like to set a global environmental variable after boot and login.  By global, I mean an environment variable that can be accessed by any program (running under the current user).

Basically at any given point, say 10 minutes after boot, I would like to be able to run a script that would set some global environment variables.  Is this possible?

**Background**

I am having some trouble with gpg-agent in Ubuntu 14.04.  Programs use environmental variables to connect to the gpg-agent process.  My trouble is with multiple instances of gpg-agent running (only one of which has ssh-support enabled).  I would like to be able to kill all existing instances of gpg-agent and start a new one with ssh-support.  However, for other programs to be able to access the new instance, I need the environmental variables to be made global.  Doing it during startup hasn't worked for me since the other gpg-agent seems to start after mine, replacing the environmental variables.

Comment: You can't run a script that will magically inject environment variables into running processes. Would running a script that creates a config file that other processes can read help?

Comment: Why not use a file? The behaviour you want isn't easily achievable. Using a file seems like an elegant solution

Comment: A file sounds great, but I don't think it will work in my situation since the programs are looking for predefined environmental variables.

Comment: This looks like it might work for you,but it requires that the given application uses a particular pam module http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641569/486399

Comment: This is an XY problem: your real problem is that `gpg-agent` is not configured properly, and you *think* that the solution is to set an environment variable visible to all processes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I face a closely related problem. I have an `ssh-agent` running on a machine under the umbrella of its graphical desktop, but I access the same machine remotely. That shell doesn't have the environment variables.

For that I use a script which looks through `/proc` for Bash processes, and scrapes through their `/proc/<pid>/environ` entries, looking for `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AGENT_SOCK` variables. Then it re-creates these entries in shell syntax, so this whole "env scraping script" can be `eval`-ed in the new shell.

Basically, "go through `/proc` to find what other Bash-es are using for their agent variables and reproduce that in this session".